# Application does not display with Core i5 7400

Tags: multi-core

I'm using a core i5 7400, no off board video card, the motherboard is Asus B250M-PLUS-BR, Ubuntu 16.4 16.10 or 17.4 which has the bug of not opening in the desktop some application, for example synaptics and monitor system.
The curious thing is that using ubuntu 16.x or 17.x the bug remains. To work around this fault I'm using a hard disk, coming from another computer, with ubuntu 16.4 already installed. This makes the applications work normally. Is there a solution to using core i5 7400 with ubuntu?

Comment: If a hard disk from another computer works normally, there is no bug.

Comment: If I install ubuntu on another PC, with a processor other than core i5 7400, and remove the hd from that PC and install on the new Pc, core i5 7400, ubuntu works normally. The bug appears when I use the core i5 7400 and asus B250M-PLUS motherboard combination.

Answer (score 0):

Even if our machine has only one monitor, the SO maybe identifying a second monitor.

Open the display configurations and check If there is a second monitor identified as 'built in display'. 
This display must be deactivated. 
Hope it helps.